# A [suffix] sitting [prefix] [infix] corner solving [whole]

Tags: riddle, wordplay, affix-riddle

Inspiration by [@risky mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70545/risky-mysteries)

A [suffix] sitting [prefix] [infix] corner solving [whole].

Rule and Clue: The infix and suffix may not be exactly same as the whole, such as:

| Infix or suffix | Whole |
| --- | --- |
| **zen** | thou**sand** |
| **edge** | marri**age** |
| **trip** | con**trib**ution |

Comment: Two months without an accepted answer: I guess it's time for clues... or for your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

A possibility is

> A **gramps** sitting **in** **a** corner solving **anagrams** (~in-a-gramps); describing an elderly man, perhaps someone's grandfather, absorbed in rearranging letters to form words while sitting in a corner.

As mentioned in the question, some of the affixes are sound-alikes rather than exact strings.

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be

> INEQUALITIES

Reasoning

> A **TEASE** sitting **IN A** corner solving **INEQUALITIES**.
>  where I've used homophones **e** in **inequalities** with **a**,
>  **ties** with **tease**.

Comment: Sitting qually in a corner?

Answer (score 0):

Probably far-fetched:

> ENIGMAS
>
>  A mouse sitting in a corner solving ENIGMAS (in-a-g-mouse)

Comment: As a non-native writer, my idea of sound-alike words is pretty loose. So, if my answer really looks silly, please tell me and I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is

> ACROSTIC(s)

Because

> A TICK sitting CROSS A corner solving ACROSTIC(s).

I think it sounds better in the plural, but the sentence starts with "A," so I have to go with the singular.

I've just realized I've mixed up PREFIX and INFIX, but I'll leave the answer up anyway.